# Thévenin with dependent source and unknowns?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I have this problem where I need to find the Thévenin resistance. However I have a bit of a trouble of thinking how I should do it with a dependent source and that everything is unknown. How should I go about this problem?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I'm trying to figure out the third equation that involves V1. Could some try to give a hint on how to manage that?

[image]

Comment: It says to assume that all the values are known, does it not?

Comment: Yes, I have a trouble on how to solve it when there is a dependent source involved. As you suggest I can just assume some values on all the sources, however still, it's the dependent source that makes it hard for me.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to determine the Thévenin equivalent circuit of a given electrical diagram. In the present case, there is one fixed source and a voltage-controlled current source. According to a [paper](https://leachlegacy.ece.gatech.edu/papers/superpos.pdf) written by Mr. Leach, it is possible to apply the superposition theorem and alternatively turn sources on and off, even the controlled one. The trick, in this case, is to start by determining the control variable, \$V_1\$ in this exercise. Here we go:

[image]

Once the control variable is obtained, then you can apply superposition again to obtain the Thévenin voltage:

[image]

Then, to determine the Thévenin resistance, short the \$V_A\$ source and install a test generator across the output from which you want to determine \$R_{th}\$. This is exactly as what is described following the fast analytical techniques to determine time constants. Here, you can simplify the analysis because \$R_3\$ is in parallel with the intermediate result which itself is in series with \$R_2\$. The circuit to solve ends up being the simple below one:

[image]

Once this is done, a quick Mathcad sheet and a SPICE simulation tell you if this is good or not. In SPICE, a .TF (transfer function) calculates the output impedance at the considered node, directly giving the small-signal resistance \$R_{th}\$ you want:

[image]

Applying superposition to controlled sources represents a valid extension of the original theorem as this example shows.

Answer (score 0):

One way to find the Thevenin equivalent circuit is to find the open-circuit voltage and the short-circuit current, then use Ohm's Law to find \$R_{TH}\$.

There are a number of general circuit analysis techniques you could use, such the node-voltage or mesh-current techniques.

If you make a significant effort to solve this on your own but have a specific problem or question, ask another question and we will try to help.

Comment: I know that I have to turn off the independent source and apply either a voltage or current source between terminal A and B. However I don't really understand how to know if I should use a current source or voltage source. The fact that the sources values are unknown are making it difficult for some reason.

Comment: No, you don't **have to** deactivate the independent source. That is part of one possible approach. If the source **values** are unknown it just means that your answer will be expressed as a function of those unknown values rather than as a specific number.

Comment: After trying alot I am stuck on finding my third equation so I can calculate Vth = Voc. If you would be so kind, I have edited my question and added a picture on how far I have come. However, as I stated I am stuck on finding the third equation in relation to V1.

Comment: You don't need a third equation. You only have two node voltages to find, Va and Vb, so two equations are enough. Do you understand how Vb is related to Voc?

Comment: Vb and Voc has the same voltage. When I’m trying to set up the equations, I put the second equation on the right lead. However when I try to solve for Vb I cannot complete, because I have Va and V1 (in kV1) as unknowns too. That’s where my problem is and my professor suggested that I need to find a third equation, because I have three unknowns (Vb, Va and V1) but only 2 equations.

Comment: If you write a KVL equation for the left loop, the one with both sources and one resistor, you can write an expression that relates VA, V1, and Va. Maybe that is the third equation you need.

Comment: Could it possibly be kV1 + V1/R1 = 0 ?

Comment: No, there will be current through R2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider adding a test source to the open terminals. Then dividing the voltage by current across those terminals. That way you can determine the thevenin resistance.